# Parsing nested JSON from a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON like following

```
[
  {
    "name": "humidity",
    "location": "Apartment",
    "location-id": "lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_40",
    "resolution": 3600,
    "data": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1541253600,
        "value": 38.3033332824707,
        "good_quality": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "humidity",
    "location": "Apartment",
    "location-id": "lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_36",
    "resolution": 3600,
    "data": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1541253600,
        "value": 37.410831451416016,
        "good_quality": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "humidity",
    "location": "Apartment",
    "location-id": "lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_41",
    "resolution": 3600,
    "data": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1541253600,
        "value": 39.43888854980469,
        "good_quality": true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to print data value (i.e 37.410831451416016) where location-id=lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_36. here data is a list. I tried list to string, then string to json. e.g myjson['data']['value']

Comment: What is stopping you indexing it as a list?

Comment: problem is "data" is a list [] not {}

Comment: Exactly, and lists items are accessed by index just like dictionaries are by keys. So, index the list to get the dictionary it contains. A single-item list is valid and you'd access the object at that index with `[0]`

Comment: i got list indices must be integers or slices, not str when i print myvar['data']['value']

Comment: Are you reading my comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This One:

```
for i in a:
    if i['location-id'] == 'lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_36':
        print(i['data'][0]['value'])
```

Output:

`37.410831451416016`

Answer (score 1):

Your inner data is a list of dicts as well. You can do it like so:

```
import json

t = """ 
[
  {
    "name": "humidity",
    "location": "Apartment",
    "location-id": "lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_40",
    "resolution": 3600,
    "data": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1541253600,
        "value": 38.3033332824707,
        "good_quality": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "humidity",
    "location": "Apartment",
    "location-id": "lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_36",
    "resolution": 3600,
    "data": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1541253600,
        "value": 37.410831451416016,
        "good_quality": true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "humidity",
    "location": "Apartment",
    "location-id": "lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_41",
    "resolution": 3600,
    "data": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1541253600,
        "value": 39.43888854980469,
        "good_quality": true
      }
    ]
  }
]"""

data = json.loads(t)

# filter all datasets from data that match the location-id searched for
datasets = list(filter( lambda x: x["location-id"] ==
                       "lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_40" , data))

# if results filtered, iterate over all results and do some printouts
if datasets:
    for ds in datasets:
        for key in ds:
            print(key," => ",ds[key])

    print()

    # print the first data's data-lists first dictionarys value 
    print(datasets[0]["data"][0]["value"])
```

Output:

```
name  =>  humidity
location  =>  Apartment
location-id  =>  lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_40
resolution  =>  3600
data  =>  [{'timestamp': 1541253600, 'value': 38.3033332824707, 'good_quality': True}]

38.3033332824707
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pandas` like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json(json)
data = df[df['location-id']=='lh_vuoreksenkoulutuskeskus_tampere_36']['data']
value = list(data)[0][0]['value']

value
37.410831451416016
```

Comment: Why would you use pandas to parse JSON? This ends up being more complicated than the json module for no reason

Comment: Because I'm a Pandas fan :D

Comment: I was just trying out the read_json capabilities to check if it had a way to parse the nested value, but I couldn't find.

Comment: Just use the json module like in Patrick's answer. You may be a fan of pandas but surely you see this is insane overkill? A full data science library with all its own syntax and methods to parse a nested python structure; just to throw it back into a list.